# Html/Javascript work into I add any html to be displayed above the js script

Tags: javascript, html

If I don't add any elements to be displayed/html above the script tag, everything works perfectly. Why if I add anything above it like the h1 tag do I get an error? Specifically, this is the error:

It also wants me to give more details on the post for some reason or it will not allow me to post. Still. I have already written this much commentary. How much more does it want me to write?

```
index.html:732 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'word')
    at index.html:732:37
```

Comment: (the error line: word = syncData[counter].word; in the while loop else statement).

```
<body>
  
  
  <audio id="audiofile" src="test.mp3" controls></audio><br>
  <div id="subtitles">
    
  </div>
  **<h1>hi</h1>**
  <script>
    (function(win, doc) {
      // JavaScript code

      var transcript = "a bunch of chinese text I can't write because or else the SO bot thinks it is spam";
       var syncData = 
      [{
        "endTime": "1.200",
        "startTime": "0",
        "word": ""
      }, {
        "endTime": "1.300",
        "startTime": "1.200",
        "word": "a"
      }, {
        "endTime": "1.800",
        "startTime": "1.300",
        "word": "中"
      }... ]
    
;

      var syncData2 = []; // New array to track sentences
      // Convert syncData to syncData2
      var sentence = (empty quotes);
      var startTime = "0";
      var endTime = (empty quotes);
      var counter = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < transcript.length; i++) {

    var word = syncData[counter].word;

    var punctuation = transcript[i + 1];
```

The error seems to appear in the following while loop:

```
    while ((!isNaN(transcript[i]) ||[ "千", "万", "亿"].includes(transcript[i]) ||["零", "一", "二", "三", "四", "五", "六", "七", "八", "九", "十", "百", "千", "万", "亿", "两"].
      includes(syncData[counter].word)) && transcript[i]!=word) {
      word = syncData[counter].word;

        if (["零", "一", "二", "三", "四", "五", "六", "七", "八", "九", "十", "百", "千", "万", "亿", "两"].includes(syncData[counter].word) && (!isNaN(transcript[i]) || ["千", "万", "亿"].includes(transcript[i]))){
          
    
            sentence+=word;

            i++;
            counter++;
            word = syncData[counter].word;
                  console.log("2)"+transcript[i] + (empty quotes) + syncData[counter].word);


        }
        else if(!isNaN(transcript[i])||[ "千", "万", "亿"].includes(transcript[i])){
          i++;
        }  
        else{
          word = syncData[counter].word;
            sentence+=word;
            counter++;
           word = syncData[counter].word;
           punctuation = transcript[i + 1];

        }
       

    }

      if (["！", "，", "。"].includes(punctuation)) {
          sentence += word + (empty quotes) + punctuation;
          endTime = syncData[counter-1].endTime;
          syncData2.push({
            startTime: startTime,
            endTime: endTime,
            sentence: sentence
          });
          sentence = (empty quotes);
          startTime = (empty quotes);
        i++;
        counter++;

     } 

      else if(startTime===(empty quotes)&& i!=0){
       startTime = syncData[counter-1].startTime;
       sentence+=word;
        counter++
      }
      else{
        sentence+=word;
       counter++;
      } 
      console.log(syncData2[syncData2.length - 1]);
  }

      var audioPlayer = doc.getElementById("audiofile");
      var subtitles = doc.getElementById("subtitles");
      console.log(syncData2);
      console.log(Array.isArray(syncData2));

      createSubtitles();

      function createSubtitles() {
        for (var i = 0; i < syncData2.length; i++) {
          var element = doc.createElement('span');
          element.setAttribute("id", "s_" + i);
          element.innerText = syncData2[i].sentence;
          subtitles.appendChild(element);
        }
      }

      audioPlayer.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(e) {
        syncData2.forEach(function(element, index) {
          if (
            audioPlayer.currentTime >= parseFloat(element.startTime) &&
            audioPlayer.currentTime <= parseFloat(element.endTime)
          ) {
            subtitles.children[index].style.color = '#E4E4E4';
                subtitles.children[index].style.fontWeight = 'bold';
          } else {
            subtitles.children[index].style.color = '#595757';
            subtitles.children[index].style.fontWeight = 'normal';
          }
        });
      });
    })(window, document);
  </script>
</body>
```

I tried a variety of html elements (image tags, h1) and all cause this error. And note, I took out some of the chinese characters just for the post so SO would accept it (I guess the bot doesn't like Chinese characters, it works after removing).

It also wants me to give more details on the post for some reason or it will not allow me to post. Still. I have already written this much commentary. How much more does it want me to write?

Comment: The error is saying that `syncData[counter]` is undefined, so it does not have a property `word`. Use console.log or step-by-step debugging with your browser dev-tools to debug the loop.

Comment: @PeterKrebs Ok I did a console.log in the while loop where the error was. BIZARRE. I get output of a bunch of random traditional chinese characters that are not even related to the chinese (simiplifieid) in my transcript/words. Again, this only happens once I put any html element like a H1 tag above the JS. What could this possible be? Even adding an empty <div></div> above the <script> tag also makes this happen.

Comment: Do you get any further errors in the console? The script stops execution if you have an error so it might be working with errors fixed. You should always make sure you don't access your array out of bounds.